# Get autoincremented generated key with apache dbutils without Statement

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, apache-commons-dbutils

I don't use Statement to execute queries. The methods look like

```
public static int insertIntoUserTable (String username, String password) {
        String query = "insert into user (username, password) values (?, ?)";
        QueryRunner run = new QueryRunner(FeedDbDataSource.getDataSource());
        ResultSetHandler<User> resultHandler = new BeanHandler<>(User.class);
        try {
            run.insert(query, resultHandler, username, password);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // handle
        }
        return ;
    }
```

How can I get the id of inserted row (without making additional select * from user where...)?

Answer (score 0):

Noting Ollie's deleted answer visible to only some people, I would create a stored proc. It performs the `INSERT`, then returns a 1 row 1 column result set of `LAST_INSERT_ID()` at the end of it just after the `INSERT` call.

So your call would be to the stored proc passing whatever parameters necessary to be picked up for the `INSERT` part, followed by the aforementioned.

```
INSERT student (lastname, ...) values (pLastName, ...); 
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() AS `ai_id`; -- ai_id becomes the column name
```

The ID returned is relative to this connection, shielded from any interference by other users, and prior to the return of any objects to a connection pool.

Fortunately these types of calls are infrequent for the most part.

If you need help with a stored proc wrapper, just ask.